# 3d movement around a sphere

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, 3d

I'm working in 3d for the first time in a long time. Basically I'm rotating a sphere and projecting x y z cords to place things on the surface based on the spheres X and Y rotation.

Heres the code im using:

```
    #define piover180 0.01745329252f

    GLfloat cosy = cos(yrot * piover180);

    island[i].x = rad * sin(xrot * piover180)* cosy;
    island[i].y = rad * sin(yrot * piover180);
    island[i].z = rad * cos(xrot * piover180) * cosy;
```

Problem is the Xrot positioning works fine but the Yrot placement always draw the objects into the north and south pole so they all cross at the top, which isn't correct for rotating. I need a way to solve this. Here's a picture to help explain:

[image: Screenshot]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, let me know if you need any more information?

Comment: You seem to be confused over the order of rotations. Your formula first applies the y rotation, then the x rotation. Your expectation on changing the yrot value is as if it was executed last.

Answer (score 2):

The code sample you pasted is incomplete, because you didn't show how you applied these calculations via glRotate et al. Here's how I would do this. Although you could certainly optimize it by doing the matrix calculations yourself in one step, it's likely not necessary.

```
// Move object out to its radius
glTranslatef(radius, 0, 0);

// Apply latitudinal rotation (aka "Yrot")
glRotatef(latitude, 0, 1, 0);

// Apply longitudinal rotation (aka "Xrot")
glRotatef(longitude, 0, 0, 1);
```

After that, you can do the drawing. You'll also want to wrap the whole thing in calls to `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` to isolate this transformation.

Comment: This is how I was transforming glTranslatef(island[i].x,island[i].y,island[i].z+camZoom);

Comment: Applied your translate based method and it works in exactly the same way. The sideways rotation of the globe makes the "island" rotate and place in the correct way (imagine spinning a globe horizontally) but when its rotated vertically the dot always ends up on the exact pole rather than circling like a real life globe. Hope this makes sense

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. What coordinate system do you want to use? What do "Xrot" and "Yrot" represent here?

Comment: Xrot is just Horizontal rotation and Yrot is Vertical. Rotating a sphere on just the Vertical direction should cause the "island" to rotate in a circle maintaining its X position and just moving upwards. The problem is any Y movement causes the "island" to move towards the pole (moving upwards makes it go to the north pole) and when it meets the middle vertically it is back to its origional X. Rotating only horizontal the "island" behaves as expected - moving on an 2d plane of rotation. Only the Vertical rotation have a problem. It has me stumped. If you need a video i can show you. Thanks!

Comment: Talking about "X" and "Y" on a sphere has little meaning, and I think you need to re-think how you express the coordinates. The most common coordinate system for spheres is the latitude/longitude (aka azimuth/altitude) system that I described.

Comment: Yeah I think youre right I will give it a try, Currently its just 2 sets of angles covering 360, but one problem is this covers the same area twice but in reverse depending on the relationship. I need -90 > 90 and -180 to 180. This should solve at least some of my problems thanks

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, i managed to come up with a solution based on 2 angles

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it using the Spherical Coordinate System.

Here's the code:

```
island[i].x = rad*sin(xrot*(PI/180))*cos(yrot*(PI/180));
island[i].y = rad*sin(xrot*(PI/180))*sin(yrot*(PI/180));
island[i].z = cos(xrot*(PI/180));
```

Here are the equations:

```
x = r sinq cosf
y = r sinq sinf
z = r cosq

r = (x2 + y2 + z2)1/2
q = tan-1(z/(x2+y2)1/2)
f = tan-1(y/x)
```

Just in case anyone could do with it, it's perfect for camera control or any exact 3d coord calculations you need to do.

Reference: http://electron9.phys.utk.edu/vectors/3dcoordinates.htm